# Should I delete the default "id" field when using a string primary key in Rails / Postgres?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, heroku

This is a build on a question [I asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11494417/how-to-isolate-id-from-string-primary-key-in-heroku-postgres) (without any luck).

I have a model where I'm using a string as a primary key:

```
class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
   self.primary_key = "employment_id"
end
```

This table also contains the Rails default 'id' field, with a uniqueness constraint.

When I add a new employee locally it all works fine, with Rails automatically generating a new unique id.

However when I run this on Heroku Postgres it appears to treat 'id' and 'employment_id' as the same field. I tried to get around this by manually setting a unique id, but still get this behaviour:

```
Employee.new do |s|

  max_id = Employee.maximum(:id)  
  puts max_id.to_s             # => 1803 

  s.employment_id = "fred_01"      
  s.id = max_id + 1 

  puts employment_id.to_s      # => 1804

end
```

I'm running postgres 9.1.3 locally (and Heroku is on 9.1.4). I'm on Rails 3.2.3.

My questions are:

- Any idea what's going on here?
- Do you think it's right that I'm using employment_id as the primary key?
- Would help if I deleted the 'id' field?
- Is there any other best practice you would recommend?

Thanks for your help!

Derek.

**Edit:**

Adding migration file as requested:

```
class CreateEmployees < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :employees do |t|
      t.string :employment_id, :unique => true
      etc...
    end
  end
end
```

**EDIT**

Very kind of nobody to point this out, but it's clear to me now that the real answer is "Just because you can, doesn't mean you should!"

Comment: Did you put `:id => false` on your migration, when creating the table and the model?

Comment: Or you can look in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200568/using-rails-how-can-i-set-my-primary-key-to-not-be-an-integer-typed-column

Comment: please include your migration file here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200568/using-rails-how-can-i-set-my-primary-key-to-not-be-an-integer-typed-column) post, it should solve the problem:

```
class CreateEmployees < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :employees, {:id => false} do |t|
      t.string :employment_id, :unique => true
      etc...
    end
  end
  execute "ALTER TABLE employees ADD PRIMARY KEY (employment_id);"
end
```

Also in your model:

```
class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
  set_primary_key :employment_id
  ...
end
```

Comment: Great stuff.  Much appreciated!

Comment: If you're using rails 3.2 or higher, the set_primary_key method was deprecated.  The Rails 3.2 release notes - Section 8.1 and it suggests using an assignment method instead like  "self.primary_key= : employment_id"

Answer (score 1):

An update for Rails 4.2.0 and Postgres in case it helps anyone...

Put a `id: :string` in the `create_table` options:

```
class FooMigration < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :foo, id: :string do |t|
      t.string :name, null: false
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

rake db:migrate

```
== 20150225043441 FooMigration: migrating ===========================
-- create_table(:foo, {:id=>:string})    -> 0.0031s
== 20150225043441 FooMigration: migrated (0.0032s) ==================
```

rails db (and \d foo)

```
psql (9.3.6)
Type "help" for help.

bar_development=# \d foo
                  Table "public.foo"
   Column   |            Type             | Modifiers 
------------+-----------------------------+-----------
 id         | character varying           | not null
 name       | character varying           | not null
 created_at | timestamp without time zone | not null
 updated_at | timestamp without time zone | not null
Indexes:
    "foo_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
```

I end up with a 'not null' string column with a primary key index.

Using a column name other than `id` is more involved.

Edit (26 Feb 2015): there seems to be a bug in rails when it generates the `schema.rb` file. It will not record the custom primary key state, you'll need to go in and edit it to add the `id: :string` option to the `create_table` call.

ie.

```
create_table "foo", id: :string, force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "name",       null: false
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end
```

The crappy part: that change will be undone every time you do a migration. You'd have to keep a close eye on the file content (or write a test :) ).

The bug is fixed in [PR 18228](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/18228), merged to rails:master on Jan 3, 2015.